# Get User input from action sheet in ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

`getcode` is the value that I want to take from the user and pass it the `getCoupon` function then I want to pass the result to another alert and display the Coupon in the message property without getting `[object object]`

```
showPrompt(message,offer,getcode) {
    this.peopleservice.getCoupun(offer,getcode).subscribe(data=> this.Code=data);

    let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: 'code',
          message: message,
          inputs: [{
              name: 'Code',
              placeholder: 'code',
          }],
          buttons: [{
               text: 'Cancel',
               handler: data => {
               console.log('Cancel clicked');
          }
        },{
           text: 'ok',
           handler: data => {
                this.Coupun();
          }
        }

     Coupun(){
        let prompt = 
            this.alertCtrl.create({
                 title: ' code ',
                 message:"the result for the getCoupun request",
                 buttons:[{
                    text: 'Cancel',
                    handler: data => {
                        console.log('Cancel'); 
                        }
                     }]
            });
            prompt.present();

     }
```

Comment: are you working with firebase

Comment: what is your `this.peopleservice.getCoupun()` code?

Comment: No l'm not using firebase and people services is a http request getCoupun(Offer,code){
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:8888/PeopleService/GetStore&Offers/getCoupun.php?Offer='+ Offer +'&Code='+Code)
    .do(this.logResponse)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.catchError); 
}

Comment: I can't understand what is your problem. First, you show a prompt alert with an input. Then user input something and press ok. You want to handle that but you don't know how to do, right?

Comment: yes, your are correct I want to take the user input and for example pass to the Coupon function do I pass the name property??

Comment: nerve mind I found the answer all I need to do get the data it to type data.code

Answer (score -2):

Steps for the implementation

1. Install cordova action sheet plugin
2. In controller

   `      import { Component } from '@angular/core';
     import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
     import { ActionSheet, ActionSheetOptions } from '@ionic-native/action-sheet';
     let buttonLabelsToShow = ['Share via Facebook', 'Share via Twitter'];
     @Component({
       selector: 'page-action-sheet-demo',
       templateUrl: 'action-sheet-demo.html',
     })
     export class ActionSheetDemoPage {
       /** Action Sheet Options */
       options: ActionSheetOptions = {
         title: 'Share This Image with the World',
         subtitle: 'Choose from the various Options',
         buttonLabels: buttonLabelsToShow,
         addCancelButtonWithLabel: 'Cancel',
         addDestructiveButtonWithLabel: 'Delete',
         destructiveButtonLast: true
       }

   ```
   constructor(private actionSheet: ActionSheet, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
   }

   ionViewDidLoad() {
     console.log('ionViewDidLoad ActionSheetDemoPage');
   }

   openActionSheet() {
     this.actionSheet.show(this.options).then((buttonClickedIndex: number) => {
       console.log('Button pressed is' + buttonClickedIndex)
     }).catch((err) => {
       console.log(err)
     });
   }
   ```

   }`

   3.In template `<button ion-button (click)="openActionSheet()">Button</button>`